# How can I display images 3 by 3, starting at position 0, by clicking the buttons according to the position of the button, in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have a total of 9 images when I click on button 1 it starts at image 1 because the counter is 0, when I click on button 2 it moves to image 4 and the counter is equal to or is 3 and if I click on button 3 moves to image 7 and counter is equal to or equal to 6.

and should work backwards, if I click on button 3 it starts on image 7 and if I click on button 2 it should move to image 4 and if I click on button 1 start on image 1

I have three buttons when I click on the first one I am in position 0 and the counter is equal to 0, when I click on the second button I am in position 1 and the counter is equal to 3, when I click on button 3 I am in position 2 and the counter is equal to 6.

My intention is that whenever I click on button 1, the counter is equal to 0 and if I click on button 2, the counter is equal to 3 and if I click on button 3, the counter is equal to 6, that is, it will increase by three values when the position of the button is higher and will decrease by three when the position of the button that has been clicked is lower.

The variable i is the position of the button that is clicked. The variable img is the number of the current image to be compared

Let's say it would look like this using if but what I want is to make it simplified

```
let counter = 0;

if(i == 0){
    // here the counter is equal to 0, counter = 0;
    img[counter].style.background = "#acc2fa";
}else if(i == 1){
    counter = 3;
    img[counter].style.background = "#084cf6";
}else if(i == 2){
    counter = 6;
    img[counter].style.background = "#031a53";
}
```

I tried to simplify, but it does not work because when the condition is equal to 0 it is not fulfilled.

```
if(i !=0 ||( img % 3 ) == 0){
    counter = counter + 3;
}
```

Any suggestions on how I could solve my problem thanks

Comment: *when I click on button 2 it moves to image 4* -- WHAT moves to image 4?  *the number of the current image to be compared* -- compared to WHAT?  You haven't mentioned any comparing up to this point.

Comment: When I click on button 2, it goes to the image that is in position 4, that is, image 4 is previewed as if it were the first. When I click on button 3, it goes to the image that is in position 7, that is, image 7 is previewed as if it were the first. When I click on button 1, it goes to the image that is in position 1, that is, image 1 is previewed as if it were the first.

Comment: So that you understand the context, I am making a slider with the images and I want to start according to the position of the button that is clicked but taking into account that I divide them three by three as if it were a pagination to visualize them faster.

Comment: You never mentioned previewing or comparing anything.  I really have no idea what you are building.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is exactly what @munleashed did at the bottom, in his example, take a look at it so you can understand it, any other suggestions on how to do it.

Comment: You could improve the post by defining "it" before using it, and not abbreviating "should be set to" or "has been set to" to "is". If that is what you mean, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll(".image");


const onClick = (ev) => {

  // Here we are reseting background for all images 
  // In this way we do not have reason to save counter (and previously selected image)
  [...images].forEach(img => img.style.background = "none")

  const value = ev.target.dataset.index;

  const index = (+value)*3 - 3;

  images[index].style.background = "#acc2fa";

}
```

```css
.image-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  padding-block: 10px;
}

.image {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  
  <div class="image">1</div>
  <div class="image">2</div>
  <div class="image">3</div>
  <div class="image">4</div>
  <div class="image">5</div>
  <div class="image">6</div>
  <div class="image">7</div>
  <div class="image">8</div>
  <div class="image">9</div>
  
</div>


<button data-index="1" onclick="onClick(event)">1</button>
<button data-index="2" onclick="onClick(event)">2</button>
<button data-index="3" onclick="onClick(event)">3</button>
```

What we are doing here basically is: You have three buttons, you can make 3 different functions for a click event listeners such as "onButton1Click" "onButton2Click" "onButton3Click" and then handle those callbacks. Usually its not that good approach since that kind of code does not scale (what if you want to add 5 buttons more or something like that). Here i am using data-* HTML5 attributes just to show you that possibility as well (it has some advantages, but are complex to explain in this example).

You can also avoid using them and pass "button value" directly to a click handler:

```
<button onclick="onClick(1)">1</button>
<button onclick="onClick(2)">2</button>
<button onclick="onClick(3)">3</button>
```

And then change onClick handler:

```
const onClick = (value) => {

  [...images].forEach(img => img.style.background = "none")

  const index = value * 3 - 3;

  images[index].style.background = "#acc2fa";

}
```

You asked for this line:

```
const index = (+value)*3 - 3;
```

plus unary operator (`+value`) converts string to a number. So `+"3"` is the same as `3`. We needed that in case when we used data-* attribute (in my first example) since the value is string and we needed number.

"Formula" `value * 3 - 3` is not any math. I just heuristically figured out that thats a pattern for your example.

Value = 1 => 1 * 3 - 3 = 0 (zero index thats first image)

Value = 2 => 2 * 3 - 3 = 3 (3 index thats fourth image)

Value = 3 => 3 * 3 - 3 = 6 (6 index thats seventh image)

Comment: An answer that consists of only code with no explanation is not usually a good answer.  You need to explain what you've done and how it applies.

Comment: Could you explain to me what this line does or more simplified. (+value)*3 - 3; @munleashed

Comment: I understand it, thank you, If there is another way to do it, let me know. It's always interesting to know how you solve a problem. I'll learn from you too, thanks. I'll try to do it without data-index.

Comment: Sorry i thought that from the code its enough self-explanatory. I updated my comment with explanation.

Comment: I had already understood, it thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The posted code doen't reset the background of an image that has been clicked already. Try initializing the counter by putting `let counter = 0;` in application code, in scope of the click handler but **not** within it. Then, in the click handler, clear the current `img[counter]` before setting it according to `i`:

```js
img[counter].style.background = "revert"; // clear image background

if(i == 0){
    counter = 0; // move resetting `counter` to zero here
    img[counter].style.background = "#acc2fa";
}else if(i == 1){
    counter = 3;
    img[counter].style.background = "#084cf6";
}else if(i == 2){
    counter = 6;
    img[counter].style.background = "#031a53";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, although I already solved my problem by modifying the solution given by @munleashed